# Should we use WakefulBroadcastReceiver when perform network operation from receiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I am using `BroadcastReceiver` in my application and starting `Service` not `IntentService` from there in which I am doing network operation.

Do I need to use here `WakefulBroadcastReceiver` to keep CPU awake until network operation is completed in `Service`?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

While searching about your problem. I got this link.

https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/i6MzCp1NyzF

http://porcupineprogrammer.blogspot.com/2014/02/when-do-you-absolutely-need.html

Please check. It might be helpful for you.